# not able to select added rows in a table JQuery

Tags: jquery-ui

i'm adding rows to table dynamically, but the problem is i'm not able to select or activate when i click on the added rows, bellow is my code. same code is working for static rows.

$('.dataGrid tr').bind('click', function(){
            $('.dataGrid tr').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('').appendTo(table) 
            .append($('').text(pos.posId)) 
            .append($('').text(pos.posName)) 
            .append($('').text(pos.posAddress));

please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method there instead of `click` for dynamically generated elements.

```
$('.dataGrid tr').live('click', function(){
  $('.dataGrid tr').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding new rows to a table does not automatically add the event listener you need.

Create a function that does two things:
1. Add/insert a row to the table.
2. Bind the same event listener to that row, that you are binding to the static rows.